# Symfony2 POST method controller

Tags: symfony, variables, post

I have a problem with a form and POST method.
I create a form in a controller like this:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('ricerca_index'))
        ->setMethod('POST')
        ->add('search', 'text',array(
                'label'=>'Cerca',
                'required'=>false))
        ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Cerca'))
        ->getForm();       

    $name = $request->getLocale();
    return $this->render('DtEcBundle:Default:index.html.twig',array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
```

And i configure the "**ricerca_index**" in my routing file in this way:

```
     ################################################################################
     #                               ricerca                                        #
     ################################################################################

ricerca_index:
      host:      "{_locale}.{domain}"
      locales:  { it: "/ricerca.{_format}", fr: "/ricerca.{_format}", de:    "/ricerca.{_format}" }
      defaults:  { _locale: "%locale%", domain: "%domain%", _format: "html",     _controller: DtEcBundle:Search:index }
requirements:
    _locale: "it|fr|de"
    domain:  "%domain%"
    _format:  "html|json"
    method:  "POST"

ricerca_index_www.it:
     path:      /ricerca.{_format}
     host:      "www.{domain}"
     defaults:  { _locale: "%locale%", _format: "html", _controller: DtEcBundle:Search:index }
requirements:
    _locale: "%locale%"
    domain:  "%domain%"
    _format:  "html|json"
    method:  "POST"

ricerca_index_nowww.it:
     path:      /ricerca.{_format}
     host:      "{domain}"
     defaults:  { _locale: "%locale%",  _format: "html", _controller:            DtEcBundle:Search:index }
requirements:
    _locale: "%locale%"
    domain:  "%domain%"
    _format:  "html|json"
    method:  "POST"
```

In the controller of my destination page i write in this way for print my variable in ricerca_index:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
class SearchController extends Controller {

public function indexAction(Request $request) {

    $search = $request->get('search');

    return $this->render('DtEcBundle:Search:index.html.twig',array(
            "search" => $search,

    ));

}
```

In the twig file i would print my variable form "**textbox**" and i write this code:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    {{ search }}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I don't receive error but my variable with dump is null, where is the problem?? I'm new with Symfony.. How can i do for print my variable in the page?

Comment: It looks like you have search value in different level of the post request. Try to debug request and find search field in it.

The symfony forms have a name. So when request came into controller you have to retrieve data from request by form name. To figure it out which name your form has (or to exclude this case) just look at your html. What it looks like? What the value of name attribute of search field?

Comment: @Alex i don't undestand, "Try to debug request and find search field in it".. 
This is the html code in debug:
**<input type="text" id="form_search" name="form[search]" class="form-control">**

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. You should retrieve your form in a different way. To get search value use this code: $request->get('form')['search']; or $form = $request->get('form'); $search = $form['search'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do that:

```
$searchForm = $request->get('form');
$search = $searchForm['search'];
```

instead of $request->get('search');

Your post data looks like this actually:

```
[
    'form' => [
        'search' => <search_val>,
        <...> // other values if any
    ]
]
```